# little trouble while trying to run emencia.django.newsletter

Tags: django

I did exactly (or so I think) as the docs describe to install `emencia.django.newsletter` (https://github.com/Fantomas42/emencia-django-newsletter). I installed all dependencies and `emencia.django.newsletter` from github. All installed successfully.

I also added this in my `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^newsletters/', include('emencia.django.newsletter.urls')),
)
```

I synced the database and when I give `http://localhost:8000/newsletters/` (even having logged in as admin) I get a 404 error page.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/newsletters/
```

[...]

```
^newsletters/ ^mailing/
^newsletters/ ^tracking/
^newsletters/ ^statistics/
^newsletters/ ^ ^preview/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$ [name='newsletter_newsletter_preview']
^newsletters/ ^ ^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$ [name='newsletter_newsletter_contact']
^dowser/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously there is no page at `/newsletters/` as you can see in the `urls.py`.

Try `/newsletters/mailing/`

Comment: `/newsletters/mailing/` didn't work. I tried `/newsletters/mailing/subscribe/` which worked. However I am looking for the url (or any other way) which will let me create a newsletter

Comment: You can create newsletters in django admin.